# R: calling ggmap::mapdist from within knitr

Tags: r, knitr, ggmap

I'm working in a report to use with `knitr`. In that report, I have some calls to `ggmap::mapdist`. Google limits the number of queries to 2500 a day (some other time limits apply), if they're made from the same IP (apparently it's not computer or user, as different computers in same office won't work).

The number of queries left in a given day can be checked with `ggmap::distQueryCheck()`. This number can be 2500 and **still return an error** (say, for instance, when it's run from a different computer in the same office: that computer still has 2500 queries to go, but they'll later fail with an error).

`knitr` seems to be creating a new "environment" (I don't know if that's the right word to use here, please feel free to edit) each time the knit command is given (button pushing, in this case). This causes the `distQueryCheck` to become 2500 every time, even if it will later fail (crashing the knit of the document).

code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggmap)

distancias <- data.table(origen = sample(c("cali", "medellin", "bogota", "popayan"), 2400, TRUE), destino = sample(c("cartagena", "apartado", "pasto", "buga", "tulua"), 2400, TRUE), distancia = rep(NA, 2400))

if (distancias[is.na(distancia), .N] > 0){
     (queriesLeft <- max(0, distQueryCheck()-5))
     if (queriesLeft >= 21){
          d <- distancias[is.na(distancia), .(origen, destino, distancia, rt)]
          setkey(d, "origen")
          a <- seq(21, queriesLeft, 20)
          for (i in a){
               try(d[(i-20): i, distancia2 := mapdist(origen, destino, mode = "driving")$km])
               Sys.sleep(1)
          }
          distancias[d, `:=` (distancia = distancia2), on = "rt", nomatch = 0]
     }
}
```

The `Sys.sleep` part is to avoid the by-second limit on queries and the `try` bit is to avoid some eventual network problems.

If you put that piece of code in a `knitr` document and rerun a couple times, the "renewed" 2500 queries left and the error will come.

- How can I let `knitr` know that the *real* queries left are less than 2500 (even zero)? Alternatively,
- How can I force `distQueryCheck` to aknowledge in advance that I don't have 2500 to go before producing an error?